# Unable to get "Description" into SharePoint 2010 search results XML

Tags: search, column, xml

I'm failing terribly at adding a field to my search results.

The fields (external) name is "description" and is, to my knowledge, not custom made but out of the box.

The Webpart settings already contain the element , the XML output is correct but the  tag is empty. Although the field is filled out on multiple files!

Upon further inspection, the internal name of the column appears to be "RoutingRuleDescription". Adding this to the webpart settings results in "Property doesn't exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema settings."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a full crawl?

In order to get a new property in the search results you need to do the following:

1. Create a column and fill it at least with one value
2. Do a full crawl
3. Create a managed property and map the crawled property to it
4. Do a full crawl
5. Verify the xml results and see if the property is filled.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621097(v=office.14).aspx for more details.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I'll have to get the central admin to check that out for me. Full crawl has certainly been done, but I am unsure whether the property is correctly mapped or not. Still, as it is a standard column, does it have to be manually mapped?

Comment: Create a Managed property and Map it with the appropriate Crawled property, use that Managed property in the display templates to get the data of that particular column. While creating managed property make sure it is searchable, queryable, Retrievable and if you need it for filtering also mark as Refinable.